# Cannot Pass Parameter in DbCommand in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, dbcommand

I have error when I try to pass parameter to stored procedure using DbCommand

Error returned:

> Procedure or function 'Procedure_Name' expects parameter '@TEID', which was not supplied.

These are my procedure parameters:

```
@PageNumber INT = 1,
@PageSize INT = 50,
@StartTime nvarchar(max) = -1 ,
@EndTime nvarchar(max) = -1 ,
@Month NVARCHAR(2) = -1,
@Year NVARCHAR(4) = -1,
@Day NVARCHAR(2) = -1,
@Hour NVARCHAR(2)=-1,
@TEID nvarchar(max) ,
@IgnoreIdlingTime int=120,
@DrivingTime int=300,--5 minutes by default
@CalculationFactor nvarchar(10)='speed'
```

My code to execute procedure and  pass parameters:

```
using (var context = new GPSModel())
{
    context.Database.Initialize(force: false);

    // Create a SQL command to execute the stored procedure
    var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Procedure_Name";

    DbParameter TEIDParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
    TEIDParam.ParameterName = "@TEID";
    TEIDParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
    TEIDParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    TEIDParam.Value = TEID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(TEIDParam);

    context.Database.Connection.Open();

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

I tried to remove `@` sign and send `SqlParameter` instead of `DbParameter` but still I have the same issue.

Is there any other way to do that where my stored procedure is very complex and contains multi sets

Thanks...

Comment: You have to add `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: Thats true thank you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following code to solve the error. I have added `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`. Now it works properly.

```
    var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Procedure_Name";
    DbParameter TEIDParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
    TEIDParam.ParameterName = "@TEID";
    TEIDParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
    TEIDParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    TEIDParam.Value = TEID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(TEIDParam);
```

When you are using stored procedure you have to set `CommandType` property to `StoredProcedure`, and then you should set the `CommandText` property to the name of the stored procedure. The command executes this stored procedure when you call one of the `Execute` methods.

Answer (score 0):

FOR EF core it can be done using fromSQL()

```
var tbl = new DataTable();
           tbl.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));

        foreach (var item in imageChunkRequest.ChunkNames)
        {
               tbl.Rows.Add(item);

        }
 SqlParameter Parameter = new SqlParameter();
                Parameter.ParameterName = "@udt";
                Parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                Parameter.Value = tbl;
                Parameter.TypeName = "dbo.StringList";

     _dbContext.Set<T>().FromSql("EXEC dbo.FindChunks @udt",Parameter);
```